# Copying specific range of excel cells from below a specific keyword

Tags: c#, excel, automation

I am wanting to write a C# program to copy a specific range of cells below a specific keyword. The code will identify a keyword in Excel and then copy the values of all the cells below the keyword to copy into another range.

I am using Aspose. I attempted to write code to find the keyword and can successfully return the cell the keyword is located in. What I am trying to figure out how to do is copy the range specifically below any keyword into another range. I can successfully copy one range to another range but cannot do it from below a specific keyword.

```
    Cells cellsOne = worksheet.Cells;
    FindOptions findOptions = new FindOptions();
    findOptions.LookAtType = LookAtType.StartWith;
    Cell cell = cellsOne.Find("Accounting", null, findOptions);
    //Printing the name of the cell found after searching worksheet
    Console.WriteLine("Name of the cell containing String: " + cell.Name);
    //if cell is found/value is returned
    if (cell.Name.Contains("Accounting"))
    {
         //return cell value ?
         //copy all below values (will need the cell keyword is in to do that)
         //paste below values into specific columns
         //doing it manually
         Aspose.Cells.Range range1 = cellsOne.CreateRange("A2:A10"); 
         Aspose.Cells.Range range2 = cellsOne.CreateRange("B28:B34"); 
         range1.Copy(range2);
    }
```

I have visited Aspose website but am struggling to copy a range BELOW a specific keyword. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to do it in C#, but I would advise you to find the cell which has the value, then in your "Range" statement below you could start at that cell you found before.

For example,
Cell cell = cellsOne.Find("Accounting", null, findOptions).Row;

You get for example "320", then your next line goes to that 320. Using your code:

```
  Aspose.Cells.Range range1 = cellsOne.CreateRange("A2:A10"); 
  Aspose.Cells.Range range2 = cellsOne.CreateRange("B" & cell & ":B34"); 
  range1.Copy(range2);`
```

That's what I would do in VBA.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Checking your code segment a bit, I thought your destination range is "A2:A10". Your code needs some tweaks. See the updated (complete) sample code with comments to accomplish your task for your reference. I evaluated the source range (below the searched keyword) dynamically using CellsHelper static class.
e.g.

**Sample code:**

```
Workbook workbook = new Workbook("e:\\test2\\Book1.xlsx");
Worksheet worksheet = workbook.Worksheets[0];
Cells cellsOne = worksheet.Cells;
FindOptions findOptions = new FindOptions();
findOptions.LookAtType = LookAtType.StartWith;
Cell cell = cellsOne.Find("Accounting", null, findOptions);
//Printing the name of the cell found after searching worksheet
Console.WriteLine("Name of the cell containing String: " + cell.Name);
//if cell is found/value is returned
if (cell != null)
{
   //I thought this is your destination range 
   Aspose.Cells.Range range1 = cellsOne.CreateRange("A2:A10");

   //Evaluate the the next cell after (found) cell's row and column indices.
   int startRow = cell.Row +1; //we add "1" to get the next in the same column
   int startCol = cell.Column;
   string startCell = CellsHelper.CellIndexToName(startRow, startCol);
   //Set and evaluate your end cell for the range.
   string endCell = CellsHelper.CellIndexToName(startRow + 6, startCol);
   //Create your dynamic source range based on your startCell and endCell values
   Aspose.Cells.Range range2 = cellsOne.CreateRange(startCell, endCell);
   
   //Copy the source range to destination range
   range1.Copy(range2);

}

workbook.Save("e:\\test2\\out1.xlsx");
```

Hope, this helps a bit.

You may also see the document on [copying ranges](https://docs.aspose.com/cells/net/copy-range-data-with-style/) for your further reference.

PS. I am working as Support developer/ Evangelist at Aspose.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Is there a way to set the range to be one row below a cell with a specific name? Such as, inputting everything in the cells directly below the word "Liabilities" ?

Comment: So for instance, if the cell returned is B26, we copy everything below it. If Liabilities is found in cell D10, how can we copy everything BELOW B26 into everything BELOW D10.

Comment: You need to first refer to the updated sample code  and then devise or update the logic for your custom needs. You may find the cell having "Liabilities" and then create your destination range accordingly (range should be started below the found cell). You may use multiple or nested if conditions or/and switch case to write your own code accordingly for your requirements.